# Do not re-create repositories after updating

Tags: unix, centos

We manage systems and thus manage repositories. We remove repositories which we do not use, present in `/etc/yum.repos.d/<file>`

Our problem is: after an update/upgrade of the system, CentOS automatically re-creates the repositories which were removed, which is an issue for us.

Question: Is there a command / method to ensure repositories are not re-created after an upgrade on CentOS 7 systems.

Comment: How do you remove repositories? Please, edit your question and add the relevant part of your Ansible playbook.

Comment: Edited. Ansible isn't really relevant, but just part of how we manage our systems. I'll remove the Ansible part to avoid confusion.

Comment: About which repositories exactly are you talking? The CentOS 7 system repositry?

Comment: Yes, the default ones.

Comment: Well, those files are part of the package `centos-release`, and some very basic packages depend on capabilities provided by this package. So the files get recreated each time `centos-release` is updated. I don't think there is an easy way out of this. But you question makes me wonder *why* you are doing this? What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: As stated in my question; we manage the repositories, because we own the machine. We ensure packages are only present from the repositories which we allow. We don't desire the default repo's of CentOS, thus we want is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those repositories are created by someone, the OS doesn't recreate them.
Either they are restored by an update of a RPM package such as [`centos-release`](https://pkgs.org/download/centos-release) or by an automatic script you setup/run (ansible?).

I'm not aware of an automatic method to delete a repo; I see a couple of solutions:

1. Exclude `centos-release` from the upgradable packages, by adding
   `exclude=centos-release`
   to `/etc/yum.conf` (space separated list), but this could break some updates;
2. Disable them with:

   ```
   # yum-config-manager --disable base,updates,extras,centosplus,epel,whatever
   ```

   (this can be easily scripted and put in a cron or in your ansible playbook)
3. Write a small script and place it in `/etc/cron.hourly/`, e.g. `/etc/cron.hourly/wipe_repos`, containing:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
   rm -f /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
   ```

   or, better:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
   yum-config-manager --disable base,updates,extras,centosplus,epel,whatever
   ```

I would suggest to use solution 2, since the repo files aren't overwritten by updates, but the new versions are placed along the old in `.rpmnew` files.

This is guaranteed by the flag `%config(noreplace)` in the source rpm of `centos-release`, applied to all files in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`.
You can check this by downloading the .src.rpm and opening the `centos-release.spec` file.

```
$ mkdir test && cd test
$ yumdownloader --source centos-release
$ rpm2cpio centos-release*.rpm | cpio -idmv
$ cat centos-release.spec
```

(or [search for the package online](https://pkgs.org/download/centos-release) and download the src.rpm)

Then scroll down to section `%files` and you'll notice:

```
%config(noreplace) /etc/yum.repos.d/*
```

`%config(noreplace)` means that all those files are not replaced with new files from an update, but the files from the new rpm are saved with the extension `.rpmnew`, so you'll have:

```
$ ls /etc/yum.repos.d/
CentOS-Base.repo          <-- here you set them as disabled
CentOS-Base.repo.rpmnew   <-- this comes from the update, but yum will ignore it
```

For reference, see http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/jw35/docs/rpm_config.html or https://serverfault.com/a/48819/.

Comment: I see where your going, but the 3 answers provided are more a workarond then a fitting solution.

So what I really like to do is to ensure the `centos-release` update file doesn't place repo files such as  `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo`.  And not remove the files after they have been placed.

Comment: If you disable the existing repo (with e.g. solution 2, or with some sed-fu setting `enabled=0` everywhere) updated packages (e.g. `centos-release`) shouldn't overwrite your settings.

Comment: Hhm. I'll make a test-scenario and try your method out.

Comment: I updated my answer with more details on why those files won't be touched by an update. It's the same reason why an update of httpd won't delete your web site confs.

Comment: Seems legit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I already said in the comments below the question, the reason *why* those repositories keep reappearing after an update is quite simple: the files defining the system repositories are owned by the package `centos-release` and whenever this package gets updated or reinstalled, the repositories reappear.

The package `centos-release` is a very basic package, it provides the capabilities `redhat-release` and `system-release`, and a number of other basic packages depend on it.

```
[local ~]$ rpm -q --provides centos-release
centos-release = 7-6.1810.2.el7.centos
centos-release(upstream) = 7.6
centos-release(x86-64) = 7-6.1810.2.el7.centos
config(centos-release) = 7-6.1810.2.el7.centos
redhat-release = 7.6-1
system-release = 7.6-1
system-release(releasever) = 7

[local ~]$ rpm -q --whatrequires system-release
setup-2.8.71-10.el7.noarch
grubby-8.28-25.el7.x86_64

[local ~]$ rpm -q --whatrequires redhat-release
initscripts-9.49.46-1.el7.x86_64
systemd-219-62.el7_6.5.x86_64
```

There is no easy way out of this.

But one possible solution might be to create a customized RPM package to replace `centos-release`. It should contain the pointers to your own repositories and of course needs to provide the capabilities `redhat-release` and `system-release`.

Please be aware that I have no idea if this is actually going to work, it's just something that came to my mind while thinking about the problem. It might save you the work of creating a full custom distribution derived from CentOS, which is the only other way I can think of to achieve what you seem to want.

Answer (score 0):

My solution doesn't exactly solve the problem you request ("how do I delete default repository config files forever?"), but it does stabilize your config changes.  If you zero out the files instead of deleting them, then system updates will leave your 'edited' versions unchanged.

I do feel that this is a 'hack', leaving named ghost files, but it's one I can live with.  No need to disable or customize redhat-release or system-release.

My problem was slightly different than yours - I maintained different configs for the same repositories for different situations, indicated by filename.  On updates the original files would return, leaving me with redundant and incorrect definitions.  Now they don't.